# How to change device orientation

Tags: ios, xcode7, orientation

I want to change the orientation of my app. The only thing I found is:

```
self.setDeviceOrientation(UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
```

but it says the UIA_Device_Orientation_Portrait could not be found.
Can anyone tell me why (perhaps I have to import something) or how else i could set the Orientation to Portrai mode?
thanks

Comment: When did you want to rotate,the device rotated or any time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to rotate manually, do like this:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

If automatically, do like this:

```
// ViewController.swift
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .All
}
```

And If your view controller is in a navigation/tabbar controller, please set that navigation/tabbar controller.

**UPDATE:**
This is how to control autorotate

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false // adjust this
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add landscape  option to your project.

Comment: That work perfectly well, but how can I lock the view so that the orientation doesn't rotate back? please note I want to change the view during the application and not just set a lock for the hole project

Comment: With your code it doesn't allow me anymore to change the view via code too or did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Charon3000 If you return false all the time,it'll never rotate. You can return rotateTime == 1 or other conditional expression.

Comment: yes this works. Thank you very much for your helP;))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your main `plist` adjusted to allow multiple orientations. You'll find this under the `Supported interface orientations` tag in your `plist`.